# why isn't my PHP-code in my HTML-file not working?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send info from one page to another on my website using `GET[]` command. the info is being transferred from a PHP to an HTML-file. the problem is, the PHP-code I use to receive the info isn't properly working.

This is the part from the PHP-file, all it does is enter the variable into my URL if I'm right.

```
<?php
$email_adres = "myname@gmail.com";
print("succesvol ingelogd <br /> <a href='index.html?email_adres=" . 
$email_adres . "'>terug naar homepagina</a>");
?>
```

Now the code in the HTML-file, I've tried various things:

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$email_adres = $GET['email_adres'];
//to check if it worked
print($email_adres);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
<?php
$email_adres = $GET['email_adres'];
//to check if it worked
print($email_adres);
?>
</html>
```

3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$email_adres = $GET['email_adres'];
//to check if it worked
print($email_adres);
?>
```

So after clicking on the link in the first bit of code, my URL should look like this: `index.html?email_adres=myname@gmail.com`

that works just fine

Now the result I expect to get off at least one of the options in the HTML-file is `myname@gmail.com`

but all I get is just an empty page, and neither do I see anything when I inspect the site page. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the Network tab in your developer console. Is the request giving a 200 status, or 500? If it's 500, check the server error logs for more information.

Comment: `now the code in the HTML-file, I've tried various things:` PHP does not work this way in a .html file

Comment: Simple - `$GET` variable does not exist. But `$_GET` variable does. It should be $_GET['email_adres']; instead of `$GET['email_adres']` at least. Probably typo.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Basicly PHP do not work in  .html file just rename your file from index.html to index.php and it will work. This is because Apache (or any php web server) only care about .php files.

Comment: @robinvrd, Php can work with .html files also, If you configure it to do so. I am not sure if that is good practice though

Comment: easy way to get rid the issue is rename your index.html into index.php
Also you should change $GET to $_GET as well.

Answer (score 2):

$GET will not provide you access to the variables in the URL.

$_GET will.

Try: 
    $email_adres = $_GET['email_adres'];

Also, PHP does not get processed in a .html file, so you should rename this file, and the link, to 'index.php'

Comment: thanks, it works now!